# How to remove object from array except matching value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove objects from array based on value which is not matching.

This is my items array:

```js
var items = [
  {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
  {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
  {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];

var arr=["88","108"];
```

Here I am able to removing objects from array based on matching values..But I want to keep matching value objects and need to remove unmatched objects.

This is how I'm removing matching objects from array.

```js
for(let i in arr) {
  items = items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id !== arr[i];
  });
}
```

Comment: filter by value `items.filter( item => arr.includes( item.id ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Array.filter` along with `Array.includes`:

```js
var items = [{"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},{"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}];
var arr = ["88", "108"];

const result = items.filter(item => arr.includes(item.id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` to determine the occurrence.

```js
var items = [
  {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
  {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
  {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];

var arr=["88","108"];

const filteredItems = items.filter(item => {
  if (arr.indexOf(item.id)>-1) {
    return item
    }
})

console.log(filteredItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
items = items.filter(function(item) {
    return arr.indexOf(item._id)!=-1
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `items` array into a look-up table (a `Map` of ids which point to your actual object), and then `.map()` each on your `arr`. This approach is particularly useful if you have lots of data in `items` or `arr` as it is efficient:

```js
const items = [{"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},{"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}];

const lut = new Map(items.map(({id, ...r}) => [id, {id, ...r}]));
const arr = ["88", "108"];

const result = arr.map(id => lut.get(id));
console.log(result);
```

If you can have multiple `items` which have the same `id`, then you can use `.reduce()` with `.flatMap()`:

```js
const items = [{"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"}, {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}];

const lut = items.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.id] = acc[obj.id] || [];
  acc[obj.id].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});
const arr = ["88", "108"];

const result = arr.flatMap(id => lut[id]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution -

```
var items = [
    {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
    {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];
var arr = ["88","108"];
items = items.filter( (item) => arr.includes(item.id) );
```

Comment: It's just a different approach

Comment: How is that so? Looks identical to me